# How to match and replace this pattern in Python RE?

Tags: python, regex

```
s = "[abc]abx[abc]b" 

s = re.sub("\[([^\]]*)\]a", "ABC", s) 

'ABCbx[abc]b'
```

In the string, s, I want to match 'abc' when it's enclosed in [], and followed by a 'a'. So in that string, the first [abc] will be replaced, and the second won't.

I wrote the pattern above, it matches:

```
match anything starting with a '[', followed by any number of characters which is not ']', then followed by the character 'a'.
```

However, in the replacement, I want the string to be like:

```
[ABC]abx[abc]b . // NOT ABCbx[abc]b
```

Namely, I don't want the whole matched pattern to be replaced, but only anything with the bracket []. How to achieve that?

match.group(1) will return the content in []. But how to take advantage of this in re.sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex uses lookarounds for the prefix/suffix assertions, so that the match text itself is only "abc":

```
(?<=\[)[^]]*(?=\]a)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/NDlhZf/1

So that's:

1. `(?<=\[)` - positive look-behind, asserting that a literal `[` is directly before the start of the match
2. `[^]]*` - any number of non-`]` characters (the actual match)
3. `(?=\]a)` - positive look-ahead, asserting that the text `]a` directly follows the match text.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply include `[` and `]` in the substitution?

```
s = re.sub("\[([^\]]*)\]a", "[ABC]a", s)
```

Comment: This works, but you need the replacement to be `"[ABC]a"` since that `a` is part of the match too.

Answer (score 1):

There exist more than 1 method, one of them is exploting `groups`.

```
import re
s = "[abc]abx[abc]b"
out = re.sub('(\[)([^\]]*)(\]a)', r'\1ABC\3', s)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[ABC]abx[abc]b
```

Note that there are 3 groups (enclosed in brackets) in first argument of `re.sub`, then I refer to 1st and 3rd (note indexing starts at 1) so they remain unchanged, instead of 2nd group I put `ABC`. Second argument of `re.sub` is raw string, so I do not need to escape `\`.